# Cannot add cookie through an iframe

Tags: javascript, c#, iframe, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I am dynamically creating an iframe with form on it and submitting this form like that:

```
var iframe = $("<iframe id='download_iframe' style='display: none' src='about:blank'></iframe>");
//...building that form...
form.appendTo( iframe.contents().find('body') ).submit();
```

at url where that request goes I am generating a file and setting a cookie like that:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
//...setting content type, disposition and etc...
response.Headers.AddCookies(new[]
                                    {
                                        new CookieHeaderValue("ajaxFileDownload", "true")
                                        {
                                            Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
                                            Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host,
                                            Path = "/",
                                            HttpOnly = false
                                        }
                                    });
```

So I would expect that cookie set after file downlod started and I can see `Set-Cookie` in headers:

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=engagement_list_28-10-2014.pdf
Content-Length:60027
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Tue, 28 Oct 2014 16:12:09 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie:ajaxFileDownload=true; expires=Wed, 29 Oct 2014 16:59:35 GMT; domain=localhost; path=/
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-MiniProfiler-Ids:["a8e9bef2-d31e-4f41-8896-9222d880544f"]
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-Powered-By:ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

But `document.cookie` and `$("#download_iframe").contents()[0].cookie` are empty I even can't see that cookie in browser's resources. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the page that creates the iframe being loaded from a host other than localhost. The cookie is being created for localhost and if the HTML you created is being loaded from the filesystem or some other host you will not be able to see the cookie.

Other causes could be

1) the cookie policy for your browser.

2) The time of the OS that the browser is running under. Is it greater than the Expires field?

Comment: Would the page http://about:blank cause a cross-domain issue?  I'm not sure how that page works.